# How to add array of objects to stencil context?

Tags: swift, kitura, swift-stencil

I created Codable struct Person. And I tried to add array of objects of this struct to stencil's context (See code down). But it doesn't work.

How do it right?

```
struct Person: Codable {
    public var name: String
    public var age: UInt8
    public var description: String
    public var photoURL: String

    init(name: String, age: UInt8, description: String, photoURL: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.description = description
        self.photoURL = photoURL
    }

    public static let allPersons = [
        Person(name: "Name 1", age: 18, description: "Cool man", photoURL: "https://photo.ur/1"),
        Person(name: "Name 2", age: 21, description: "Designer", photoURL: "https://photo.url/2")
    ]
}

struct MainData: Encodable {
    var products: [String]
    var persons: [Person]
}

try response.render("home.stencil", with: MainData(
    products: [ "Music", "Fashion", "etc" ],
    persons: Person.allPersons // static array with persons
))
```

[ERROR] [RouterMiddlewareWalker.swift:72 next()]  unableToRenderContext(context:)

P.S. Resolved. I had a syntax error in stencil template.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to also provide the declaration of the Person struct?

Comment: Change `Person.allPerson` to `Person.allPersons`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry, it was typo )) Code is compilable. I have a runtime error.

Comment: @ChrisBailey Yes, I added.